# Форма регистрации на сайте php Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Все работает, только не вставляются данные в таблицу базы данных. В чем может быть дело?

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
    if ($_POST) //Условие будет выполнено, если произведен POST-запрос к скрипту.
    {
    $name = trim($_POST['rname']);
    $login = trim($_POST['rlogin']);
    $password = trim($_POST['rpass']);
    $password_r = trim($_POST['rpass_r']);
    $email = trim($_POST['email']);
    $data = date('y,n,d');

   $error = false;//Создаем переменную, контролирующую ошибки регистрации.
$errortext = "<p><b><font color='red'><h3>При регистрации на сайте произошли следующие ошибки:</h3></font></p><ul>";
if (empty($name))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Вы не заполнели поле Имя пользователя!</font></li>";
} else {
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z а-яё]{2,30}$/iu",$name))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Убедитесь что Имя содержит от 2 до 30 символов и не содержит цифр</font></li>";
}
}
if (empty($login))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Вы не заполнили поле Логин пользователя!</font></li>";
} else {
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{2,20}$/i",$login))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Убедитесь что Логин содержит от 2 до 20 символов, и состоит из латинских символов и цифр</font></li>";
}
}
if (empty($password))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Вы не заполнили поле Пароль!</font></li>";
} else {
if (!preg_match("/^[a-z0-9]{3,20}$/i",$password))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Убедитесь что Пароль содержит от 3 до 20 символов, и состоит из латинских символов и цифр</font></li>";
}
}
if (empty($password_r))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Вы не заполнили поле Подтверждение пароля!</font></li>";
} else {
if ($password != $password_r)
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Поле Пароль и его Подтверждение не совпадают!</font></li>";
}
}
if (empty($email))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Вы не заполнили поле E-Mail</font></li>";
} else {
if (!preg_match("/^[-0-9a-z_\.]+@[-0-9a-z^\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/i",$email))
{
$error = true;
$errortext .= "<li><font color='red'>Не правильно заполнено поле E-Mail. E-mail должен иметь вид user@somehost.com</font></li>";
}
}
$errortext .= "</ul></b>";
if ($error)
{
echo($errortext);//Выводим текст ошибок.
} else {
     //Подключаемся к базе данных.
    $dbcon = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "123456"); 
    mysql_select_db("suitecrm", $dbcon);
    if (!$dbcon)
    {
    echo "<p>Произошла ошибка при подсоединении к MySQL!</p>".mysqli_error(); exit();
    } else {
    if (!mysql_select_db("suitecrm", $dbcon))
    {
    echo("<p>Выбранной базы данных не существует!</p>");
    }
    }
     // проверка на существование пользователя с таким же логином.
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM users1 WHERE login='$login'",$dbcon);
    $myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    if (!empty($myrow["id"])) {
    exit ("Извините, введённый вами логин уже зарегистрирован.<a href='reg.php'> Введите другой логин</a>.");
    }
        //Выполняем SQL-запрос записывающий данные пользователя в таблицу.
        $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users1 (name, login, password, email, data) Values ('$name', '$login', '$password', '$email', '$data')", $dbcon);
        if (!$sql) {echo "Запрос не прошел. Попробуйте еще раз.";}
        if ($sql)
        {
    //Выводим сообщение об успешной регистрации.    
        exit ('<div align="center"><br/><br/><br/><h3>
  Вы успешно зарегистрированы на сайте! Заполните форму входа и войдите</h3></div>');
        }
        mysql_close($dbcon);//Закрываем соединение MySQL.
        }
              }
if (($_POST && $error) || !$_POST)
{
}
?>
```

Comment: расширение `mysql_query` давно [устарело](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-query.php) и не поддерживается в последних версиях php. используйте [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.mysqli.php) или [pdo_mysql](http://php.net/manual/ru/ref.pdo-mysql.php)

Comment: уточните пожалуйста Вы получаете какую-то ошибку или сообщение?

Comment: @alina Сообщите пожалуйста, выводит ли форма сообщение "Запрос не прошел. Попробуйте еще раз."?

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте так:

```
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO users1 (`name`, `login`, `password`, `email`, `data`) Values ('" . $name . "', '" . $login."', '" . $password."', '" . $email."', '" . $data."')", $dbcon);
```

Comment: Это прямой путь к SQL-инъекциям.

Comment: @DmitriySimushev, а автор вроде и не просил переписать на PDO. :)

Comment: Это не оправдывает потенциальных проблем с результатами вашего совета. Да и в расширении `mysql` есть способы борьбы с SQL-инъекциями. Странно, что вы не в курсе.